# Delphi Programming to convert 66-bit value (Hex) to Decimal

Tags: delphi, data-structures, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large numbers in Pascal (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590171/large-numbers-in-pascal-delphi)

I am trying to convert a 66bit value to decimal.

I note that the largest data type in delphi in int64 which can only allow 64bit data.
example of delphi code for such conversion is

```
result := strtoInt64('FFFFABCDEFF123456');
```

Please advice how to use delphi to this without returning out of range error.

Muda

Comment: Why not simply use strings to represent your arbitrary-length base-N integers?

Comment: voted to close. MPARITH seems like the right solution here too.

Comment: @Andreas, because multiplying strings is a PITA?

Comment: Pedantic point: Hex digits encode 4 binary bits per digit. So you can have a 64 bit, or a 68 bit hex value, but not a 66 bit value.

Comment: I think I'll skip Delphi 64-bits, and wait for Delphi 66-bit.

Comment: do you just want to convert to a string or do you want to perform other operations?

Comment: @warren your pedantry is unfounded. A 66 bit value can be written in hex in no more than 17 hex digits.

Comment: So someone would write a function that handles 68 bit values, and then, naturally 66 bit values would work too.  So there's no such thing as "founded" and "unfounded" pedantry, there is merely pedantry, or not pedantry. As I have already been self-deprecating I see no purpose in your correction.

Answer (score 4):

Decimal in Delphi is called `currency` it uses 8 bytes = 64 bits.

You'll have to create your own type, see this article: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3772.asp
It describes how to create a 128bit integer.

Here's a bignum lib for Delphi: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27789
See also this question: [Large numbers in Pascal (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590171/large-numbers-in-pascal-delphi)

Comment: where does currency come in to integer arithmetic?

Comment: @david, it's really an integer in disguise, and the OP asked about decimal, currency is the closed match to decimal. Compare decimal in database lingo.

Comment: in this instance I understood OP to be using decimal to mean a base 10 integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford having some rounding errors, you can use the `Extended` type. That's an easy solution. I remember reading somewhere that it won't be supported in 64bit Delphi anymore though, so I personally wouldn't use it if it can be avoided.

Anyway, do you really want to do calculations on your number? Are you sure you don't just want to have an array (of bytes for example)? If that is the case, you should look at `HexToBin()`.

Documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.HexToBin

Example where you can see it in use: [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/HexEncoding_(Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/HexEncoding_%28Delphi%29)